# How can render this kind of math code similar but not exaclty like Latex?

Tags: html, latex, mathjax

The https://www.vlfeat.org/api/gmm-fundamentals.html#gmm-em website contains useful information and mathematical formulae that are not displayed correctly.

Here is an example of code that should be rendered (as math symbols) but instead is displayed exactly like this:

```
\[ p(\bx|\Theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k p( \bx_i |\mu_k,\Sigma_k), \qquad p( \bx |\mu_k,\Sigma_k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d\det\Sigma_k}} \exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2} (\bx-\mu_k)^\top\Sigma_k^{-1}(\bx-\mu_k) \right]. \]
```

or

```
A Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) is a mixture of \(K\) multivariate Gaussian distributions. In order to sample from a GMM, one samples first the component index \(k \in \{1,\dots,K\}\) with prior probability \(\pi_k\), and then samples the vector \(\bx \in \mathbb{R}^d\) from the \(k\)-th Gaussian distribution \(p(\bx|\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\). Here \(\mu_k\) and \(\Sigma_k\) are respectively the mean and covariance of the distribution. The GMM is completely specified by the parameters \(\Theta=\{\pi_k,\mu_k,\Sigma_k; k = 1,\dots,K\}\)
```

(I tried to render it on Overleaf (Latex) but not every part is rendered correctly (some parts are) but since there are some mistakes it is useless to try to render it with latex because it is similar but not exactly latex.)

In the HTML source this seem to be related to MathJax as I see this added to the header:

```
<script xml:space="preserve" type="text/x-mathjax-config">
```

I use Latex but am not familiar with MathJax.

I tried on all browsers that I know of /have installed, e.g. FireFox, Chrome, Edge, Safari.... and across different devices (ipad, pc, phone)... the website is always broken (i.e. math formulae not displayed). This same website did work years ago (around 2017) ... so i m wondering if they broke something in their HTML code.

Any idea how to render this page correctly?

Answer (score 0):

found an ad-hoc solution: saved a local copy of the webpage and it does work i.e. renders formulae. I don't have time nor am willing to try to debug the problem (maybe some kind of security feature/bug of the browsers?) even though i noticed there is an error related to the jquery library when right-click and inspecting the website online which seems strangely to have disapeard when doing the same locally. If anyone wants to get their hands dirty and try to debug this, i am curious to know the answer (I used to be interested by web programming but not anymore since CSS and all the "gas-factory" frameworks).